# How to check if screen session is running?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

Is there any way to check if a screen session is running in bash? 
For example:

```
if [screen is running]
  then
    screen -r          #if session is running then resume the session
  else
    screen "command"   #else start a new session
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading `man screen` you find the `COMMAND LINE OPTIONS`:

```
COMMAND-LINE OPTIONS
       Screen has the following command-line options:

    ...snip...

       -d -r   Reattach a session and if necessary detach it first.

       -d -R   Reattach a session and if necessary detach or even create it first.

       -d -RR  Reattach a session and if necessary detach or create it. Use the first session if more than one session is available.

       -D -r   Reattach a session. If necessary detach and logout remotely first.

       -D -R   Attach  here  and now. In detail this means: If a session is running, then reattach. If necessary detach and logout remotely first.  If it was not running create it and notify
               the user. This is the author's favorite.

       -D -RR  Attach here and now. Whatever that means, just do it.

            Note: It is always a good idea to check the status of your sessions by means of "screen -list".
```

Surely one of these would do what you want without the variable.

Answer (score 5):

Take advantage of the `PPID` (Parent `PID`) environment variable, and start with

```
$ ps -fp$PPID
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
w3       19305 19304  0 00:00 ?        00:00:00 SCREEN
+w3@aardvark:~(0)$
```

or,

```
ps -fp$PPID | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | egrep -q SCREEN
screen_is_running=$((1 - ${PIPESTATUS[-1]}))
# screen_is_running == 1 for yes, 0 for No, -1 for egrep error
```

Of course, this won't work if you've spawned, exec'ed, nohup'd or something, and made your `$PPID` not SCREEN.

If that's the case, you could build something with `pgrep`, `pstree`, `egrep` that could follow the `$PPID` chain back (stop when `$PPID` is 1).

Comment: Have a look at my updated question @waltinator

Comment: oops, I didn't put the var in quotes

Comment: If you don't care if `screen` is uyour parent process, a simple `pgrep screen` will tell you if `screen` is running anywhere on your system.